# how to store games and apps in SD card in lumia phone

Tags: 8.0, storage, micro-sd

I'm using Nokia Lumia 620. My phone memory is full  and I would like to save apps in SD card to free up phone memory. How can I do this?

Comment: Please search the site before asking a question.

Answer (score 2):

Lumia 620 with Windows Phone 8, you cannot install apps on SD Card. Wait for Windows Phone 8.1, your wish will come true :)